# Are snaps transportable between versions?

Tags: snap

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 installation with a set of snap directories in `/snap/`.  As I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, can I expect to be able to copy these snap directories directly into a corresponding `/snap/` directory on 20.04 and have them work?

Would I need to do anything else to make it work?  Or is this completely unworkable, and I'm going to need to reinstall all the snaps on the new 20.04 system?

Comment: Snaps have the benefit of allowing the same *snap* to run on any release, however your approach is wrong.

Comment: @guiverc Okay, so what's wrong with it?  What bad thing happens if I transfer snap directories and the data they store in my home/ directory to a new installation?  Do they just not work?

Comment: Snaps can be built with different *confinement* rules (https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) so don't forget there are differences in snaps.  I'd recommend reading @user5347333's answer

Answer (score 5):

It's a waste of time to copy snap directories. Snaps are not merely a bunch of files; they are files that are placed, configured, and managed by snapd.

Use the `snap` command to properly install/uninstall.

Snaps are release-independent and constantly updated (those are key advantages of them). It doesn't matter which release of Ubuntu you are using. It doesn't matter which release you are migrating to (or reinstalling). There's only one current version of snap for your channel, and everybody get it.

Snaps are unaffected by deb-based `do-release-upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`. That means old snaps are not removed, new snaps are not added (exception: A set of packages converting from deb to snap), and existing snaps are updated only by coincidence.

- If you are *upgrading* to a new release of Ubuntu, your snaps won't be touched. They will still be there.
- If you are *installing* or re-installing Ubuntu, you must reinstall your Snaps. Use `snap list` to see which snaps you currently have installed so you know what to reinstall.
- Your Snaps' data is usually stored in your /home directory, not in /snap. You generally don't need to backup anything in /snap.
- An example of the exception (packages converting from deb to snap during a release-upgrade) include LXD and Chromium. Those deb packages were replaced with a tiny transitional package that merely installed and configured the snap. After the snap is installed, those debs can be safely uninstalled.

Comment: You start by saying "Do not copy snap directories," but you don't really provide a clear reason why not in the rest of the answer.  In fact, your second paragraph about releases and versions not mattering kind of makes it sound like I can transport snaps, provided I also grab the relevant data from my home/ directory.  Is your argument that I *can't*, or that I *shouldn't*, and in either case, what do you expect to go wrong if I do?

Comment: @BoreaDeitz edited the first paragraph to explain why. Feel free to try copying snap files and let us know what happens.

Comment: Caveat: the snap daemon itself will differ between versions. So perhaps some snaps may not be installable on systems with an outdated snap daemon.